# Reading a KeyDown only once in while loop (Like KeyListener in Swing)

Tags: java, input, lwjgl

In my while loop for my OpenGL program i have some something like this:

```
     if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W)) {
     ...
     }
```

Now of course this if is getting checked multiple times per button press.
Is there a way to let it detect the button only once per press?
For example like the KeyListener in Java Swing does.

I already handle movement speed with an `elapsedTime`variable, maybe I can use that for that problem too?

Comment: Set a flag when you first detect the key press, which, while true, ignores any other key presses of the same type, until you detect the key release...

Comment: Hm, that sounds like a plan.   
But how do I check that in my if, if I only want that if-code to be executed only once per press? Because the while loop still goes on and runs through like 60 times a second, so no matter what boolean I use, it will be true all the time the key is pressed down and thus will execute the code. And if I'll use a while it will block the other code from running in that time. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You need to maintain a flag between calls to check the state. If you detect that the flag is true AND the the key is down, you can ignore it, otherwise if the flag is true and the key is not down  you need to reset the flag. You only want to run the logic when the flag is false and the key is down

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks, now I get it. You should've posted it as an answer.

Comment: Trying to tap an answer out on the phone is not my idea of fun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the instructions from MadProgrammers comment on my question, I got this working:

```
 if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W)) {
    if(wKeyUp==true) {
      wKeyUp = false;

      executeCode();
      }
   } else if (wKeyUp == false && !Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W))
        wKeyUp = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of when it comes down for the first time and when it goes back up, ideally this boolean is not defined in the local scope of the method that is called 60 times a second, but at a higher scope.

```
if (wKeyUp && Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W)) {
    wKeyUp = false;
    onNewWKeyPress();
}
else if (wKeyUp == false)
{
    wKeyUp = true;
}
```

Comment: I'll have to try it out but I'm sure I got it!

Comment: Actually, I noticed now that this is not correct. 
You mean the right thing, but the code isn't right, I'll post my code that works in a seperate answer